# Display DataTable Row in a single command

Tags: vb.net

I have a datatable I am iterating.  For now I just want to dump the whole row.

```
Dim dt as DataTable = dbCall()

  For idt = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

    debug.print( dt.rows(idt).???)

  next
```

What property is good for the ??? part?

And how would I go about finding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`DataRow.ItemArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example (separated by comma):

```
Dim rowInfo = String.Join(",", dt.Rows(idt))
```

`ItemArray` is an array of objects and `String.Join` will concat all with the given separator. Each value in the array represents one field in the table in the same order. `String.Join` uses `ToString` to convert the object to string.